# trouble with angular and flask - error message vauge

Tags: angularjs, flask

Not able to get angular to read in an object fetched via service. Error message in brower is really vauge, doesn't reference any of my code lines. I checked via Chrome Developer tools and the api call is getting made. Any ideas?

Error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at copy (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:593:21)
    at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular-resource.js:410:19
    at wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:6846:59)
    at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:6883:26
    at Object.Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:8057:28)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:7922:25)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:8143:24)
    at done (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9170:20)
    at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9333:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/lib/angular/angular.js:9303:11)
```

Service:

```
angular.module('angularFlaskServices', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('Pic', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/pic/:picId', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: { picId: '' },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  })
;
```

Angular Controller:

```
function ProfileController($scope, Pic) {
    var picsQuery = Pic.get(function(pics) {
        $scope.pics = pics;
    });
}
```

Flask View:

```
@app.route('/api/pic/')
def on_recent(): 
    if not session.has_key('access_token'):
        return 'Missing Access Token'
    try:
        api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=session['access_token'])
        recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media()
        print recent_media
        photos = []
        for media in recent_media:
            if (media.type != "video"):
                photos.append({"picId": 1, "url": media.get_low_resolution_url()})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)              
    return json.dumps(photos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service code looks good but I am not sure if you have all of your dependencies injected properly.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularFlaskServices']);
app.controller('ProfileController', [
  '$scope',
  'Pic',
  function($scope, Pic) {
     var picsQuery = Pic.get(function(pics) {
       $scope.pics = pics;
     });
}]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue - I am doing the dependencies in the same way as some other aspects of the app that are working.